# Zeroes of an entire function such that $|f(z)|>1 , \forall |z|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)|>1 , \forall |z|>1$ , then does $f(z)=0$ has only finitely many solutions ? Is $f$ a polynomial ?

Comment: $1/f(1/z)$ is holomorphic on the unit disc minus the origin, and it extends holomorphically to the origin (by Riemann's removable singularity thm). From this you see that $f$ has at most a pole at infinity, i.e. it is a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is compact $f$ can have only finitely many zeros in $\mathbb D$  since zeros of holomorphic functions are isolated. Thus there is a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ and an entire zero-free function $g$ such that $f=pg$. Then $\frac{1}{g}=\frac{p}{f}$ is entire such that $|\frac{1}{g(z)}| \leq|p(z)|\leq M|z|^n$ for some $M>0$ and sufficiently large $|z|>1$. Thus, $\frac{1}{g}$ is a polynomial (of degree at most $n$). But since $g$ has no zeros, $g$ must be constant. Thus, $f$ is a polynomial.